# what is the meaning of "defy neat racial divisions"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

"People's multiple identifications defy neat racial divisions and unidimensional political alliances."

what does it mean to "defy neat racial divisions"? and how to understand the meaning of "neat' in this phrase?

Comment: '**Neat** racial divisions' - trying to divide the population into well-defined groups according to their ethnicity.

Answer (score 1):

It means that people cannot be understood or classified only by their race or politics.

This is because their identities are concerned with multiple factors other than race, such as their religion, their nationality, their culture, their language, their gender, their politics, their interests and their physical attributes.

So it's simplistic to see someone of a particular race or religion and judge or pigeon-hole this person on that basis.

You will be aware that racial (and gender) prejudice is much in the news, often because of the damage it inflicts on people and communities and the resulting controversies. This is particularly true when those in authority belong to one (political, ethnic, religious) group or class and others are under-represented or despised.